# All shortest paths that traverse at least one node of a given group(s) of nodes

Tags: path, shortest

Basically i want to find the shortest paths for all (s,t) pairs but with several considerations. For instance the network contains several clusters/communities or group of nodes. These groups will be predefined and can be relatively large in the number of nodes.

I want to find the shortest paths for all s,t pairs that traverse at least one node e.g., from gourp1. In the general case if i have only one group of nodes the problem is reduced to the traditional betweenness centrality. Later i would like to find for all s,t pairs the shortest paths that traverse at least one node from gourp1 and group2.

Any suggestions?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, it seems to me that you are willing to get the shortest paths for individual group of nodes. If you are willing to do that, I think you are heading to the right direction.

It will be more robust if you can find the shortest paths of individual groups then combine the nodes of different groups together. That must save the time.

I think You can use Particle Swarm Optimization Algorithm for the solution of the problem. It can help you through using multiple swarms to get the shortest path of different groups. Then you can combine the nodes from different groups.

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thanks you very much for your reply. 

I looked through a couple of papers and i saw that PSO is used for the identification of shortest paths, however i am a bit concerned for its time complexity. I know that identifying short paths traversing certain nodes is expensive, however, will PSO give an acceptable computation time for large scale networks?

Comment: As you have several groups, It seems like PSO is going to be more effective than others as PSO's main working procedure matches with your requirements. And it is very effective for large scales (though it could be problem specific sometimes). If you can find best solutions of individual groups in less complexity, then overall complexity must reduce.